# The relationship between service and the executable file in Delphi

Tags: delphi, service, pipe

How, using Delphi, can communication be established between the service and an executable file? According to my research this is possible by pipe or Windows message.

I need the service to run an executable file. But the problem is that when the executable is run is does not show on Windows 7 because services on Windows 7 runs at another desktop.

Comment: Read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx

Comment: And as for part 1, pipes are fine, once you secure them right, but messages are no good because messages don't cross sessions (I think).

Comment: Possible duplicate [delphi-2009-how-to-communicate-between-windows-service-desktop-application-un](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260181/delphi-2009-how-to-communicate-between-windows-service-desktop-application-un)

Answer (score 0):

Check [Cromis IPC](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/cromis-ipc/) by Iztok Kacin. It's based on named pipes and is very lightweight, most importantly, it's very easy to use and versatile. I doubt is there any IPC library for Delphi better than Cromis IPC.